# Custom post type pagination issues

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, genesis

Having trouble implementing the pagination for custom post type ('vehicle') in Genesis child theme, I'm using Genesis : 2.0.0 in wordpress 4.1.1

I've tried placing the following code in function.php
add_filter( 'genesis_prev_link_text', 'gt_review_prev_link_text' );

```
function gt_review_prev_link_text() {
        $prevlink = '&laquo; Previous Reviews';
        return $prevlink;
}
add_filter( 'genesis_next_link_text', 'gt_review_next_link_text' );
function gt_review_next_link_text() {
        $nextlink = 'Next Reviews &raquo;';
        return $nextlink;
}
```

i've tried the following too;

```
<?php genesis_posts_nav();?>
```

The code below works, but only as 'newer' and 'older' hyperlinks, i'm trying to achieve a numeric pagination.

```
<?php previous_posts_link( '« Newer' ); ?>
<?php next_posts_link( 'Older »', $vehicle->max_num_pages ); ?>
```

Here is my custom post type archive template.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archive Vehicle(CAR)
*/
//* Force full width content
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );
//* Remove Post Info
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );

//* Remove Post Meta
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_entry_footer_markup_close', 15 );
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'genesis_post_meta' );
 /** Code for custom loop */

remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'am_custom_loop' );
function am_custom_loop(){
$paged = 1;
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ); }
if ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) { $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ); }
$paged = intval( $paged );
$args = array('post_type' => 'vehicle', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'paged'=> $paged, );
   $vehicle = new WP_query($args);
$wp_query = $vehicle;
                if ($vehicle -> have_posts() ){
?>
<div class="first arc">
<h2> View our latest used car collection from KH cars Birmingham</h2>
<p>Need a car?  Look no further, browse through our vast selection of used cars on site based in Birmingham.  </p>
</div>
<?php
                while ($vehicle -> have_posts() ){
                $vehicle -> the_post();

?>

<div class="first archivecar">
    <div class="one-fourth">  
<?php 
$images = get_field('image');
    if( $images ): 
        $image = $images[0];
?>                
            <a href="<?php the_permalink($id); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $images[0]['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            </a> 
<?php endif; ?>
         </div>
       <div class="two-fourths">
<br>
            <h3><a  style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php the_permalink($id) ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<ul class="carinfo">
    <li><p> Year: <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'year', 'year' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?></p></li>
    <li><p> Trans: <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'trans', 'trans' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?></p></li>
   <li><p> Fuel: 
  <?php   // Get terms for post
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'fuel', 'fuel' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?></li>
 <?php if( get_field('Mileage') ): ?>
    <li><p> Mileage: <?php the_field('Mileage');?></p></li>
 <?php endif; ?>
    <li><p>Color: <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'colours', 'colours' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} } ?></p></li>
 <?php if( get_field('owners') ): ?>
    <li><p>Owners: <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'owners', 'owners' );
 // Loop over each item since it's an array
 if ( $terms != null ){
 foreach( $terms as $term ) {
 // Print the name method from $term which is an OBJECT
 print $term->name ;
 // Get rid of the other data stored in the object, since it's not needed
 unset($term);
} }?></p></li>
 <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="one-fourth">

        <?php if ( get_field('price')):?>
    <p class="price"><?php the_field('price');?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<a class="btn" style="text-align:center" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">view Details</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
<?php genesis_posts_nav();?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
<?php
}
}
genesis();
```

Any Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you describe which part in the paging doesn't work, do you think it's the problem of the `$paged` var? I normally use this for it and it always works `if (get_query_var('paged')) {
  $paged = get_query_var('paged');
 } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
  $paged = get_query_var('page');
 } else {
  $paged = 1;
 }`

Comment: The pagination doesn't show at all, if i try to use the url to navigate to page 2, it just display page one again.

Comment: I also noticed that you're using the global `$wp_query` what if you change it to a custom one, e.g. `$vehicle_query`

Comment: And I didn't see anything for `$spotlight_posts_latest` that is used inside `next_posts_link `

Comment: @sdcr ive just used this <?php previous_posts_link( '« Newer' ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link( 'Older »', $vehicle->max_num_pages ); ?> and changed the wp-query to $vehicle-query and  shows the older and fewer texts. any ideas on how i can change it to a numeric one

Comment: how about removing this line `$wp_query = $vehicle;` there are some nice examples on this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link

Comment: @sdcr Doesn't make a difference. what i'm trying to achieve is a numeric pagination. but this shows a older and newer post pagination

Comment: You should not keep that line `$wp_query = $vehicle;` anyway, numeric pagination is not something that you can use directly, check out this post http://callmenick.com/2014/02/21/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination/

Comment: i've completed the question now as the paging is working now, i suggest you post a new question if you encounter other issues, have fun!

Comment: @sdcr You Sir are a Legend...Thanks a bunch... i got the numeric pagination working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i Removed $wp_query = $vehicle; and then used the code below from wordpress codex and voila it works.

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $vehicle->max_num_pages
) );
?>
```